# How to add custom scripts to Firefox context menu?

Tags: linux, firefox, context-menu

In Opera I was able to add an item to the context menu which was bound to a script on my filesystem. So, for example, when I right-clicked an image and clicked on this menu-item, the URL was passed to this local script as an argument.

Is there any way to do this with FireFox (even if it's not context-sensitive, i.e. just pass the current page's URL)?

There used to be an extension to do this called [ContextMenu Extensions](http://piro.sakura.ne.jp/xul/doc/ctxextensions/help.xml.en) but it's over a decade old and Firefox version 0.5 :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editing or adding a custom context menu item in Firefox?](http://superuser.com/questions/177903/editing-or-adding-a-custom-context-menu-item-in-firefox)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 definitely not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by writing an add-on that will add a menu to Firefox. The [Add a Menu Item to Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Add_a_Menu_Item_to_Firefox) tutorial explains how this can be done using the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation) from the Mozilla Developer Network.

There might be some other existing add-ons out there you can leverage which will modify the menus for you as well, but using the Add-on-SDK is not too difficult and gives you the most flexibility.